# Network meta-analysis. Consistency with node-spliting: ERROR

Tags: r, performance, network-programming, montecarlo, data-consistency

I am doing a network metaanalysis.
This is my data:

```
# A tibble: 29 x 5
   study                mean std.dev sampleSize treatment   
   <chr>               <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>       
 1 Geeta_Gulati         60.8    4.75         30 Beta_blocker
 2 Monica_Samuel_Avila  63.9    3.8          96 Beta_blocker
 3 Georgakopoulos       63.3    7.4          42 Beta_blocker
 4 Kaya                 63.8    3.9          27 Beta_blocker
 5 Elitok               64.1    5.1          40 Beta_blocker
 6 Jhorawat             63.9    8.56         27 Beta_blocker
 7 Nabati               57.4    7.52         41 Beta_blocker
 8 Beheshti             61.1    3.39         30 Beta_blocker
 9 Pituskin             61      4            31 Beta_blocker
10 Abuosa               59.2    2.8         116 Beta_blocker
# … with 19 more rows

data <- structure(list(study = c("Geeta_Gulati", "Monica_Samuel_Avila", 
"Georgakopoulos", "Kaya", "Elitok", "Jhorawat", "Nabati", "Beheshti", 
"Pituskin", "Abuosa", "Cochera", "Geeta_Gulati", "Georgakopoulos", 
"Dessi", "Pituskin", "Janbabai", "Geeta_Gulati", "Monica_Samuel_Avila", 
"Georgakopoulos", "Dessi", "Kaya", "Elitok", "Jhorawat", "Nabati", 
"Beheshti", "Pituskin", "Abuosa", "Janbabai", "Cochera"), mean = c(60.8, 
63.9, 63.3, 63.8, 64.1, 63.88, 57.44, 61.06, 61, 59.2, 61, 61.6, 
63.9, 66, 59, 59.93, 60.3, 63.9, 66.6, 65, 57.5, 63.3, 60.82, 
51.67, 59.3, 56, 58.2, 46.31, 60), std.dev = c(4.750654835504, 
3.8, 7.4, 3.9, 5.1, 8.56, 7.52, 3.39, 4, 2.8, 3, 4.32922519093805, 
7.5, 6, 6, 7.83, 5.03010511994542, 5.2, 6.7, 7, 5.6, 4.8, 11.28, 
6.01, 4.29, 4, 6.6, 7.04, 3), sampleSize = c(30, 96, 42, 27, 
40, 27, 41, 30, 31, 116, 30, 32, 43, 25, 33, 34, 30, 96, 40, 
24, 18, 40, 27, 40, 40, 30, 38, 35, 30), treatment = c("Beta_blocker", 
"Beta_blocker", "Beta_blocker", "Beta_blocker", "Beta_blocker", 
"Beta_blocker", "Beta_blocker", "Beta_blocker", "Beta_blocker", 
"Beta_blocker", "Beta_blocker", "Ace_inhibitor", "Ace_inhibitor", 
"Ace_inhibitor", "Ace_inhibitor", "Ace_inhibitor", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo"
)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I create my mtc.network object

```
network <- mtc.network(data.ab=data)
```

I want to evaluate consistency with node-spliting model (https://doi.org/10.1002/jrsm.1167). But R shows this error. Any idea?

```
mtc.nodesplit(network)

**Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "=="
Error in data[, "study"] == study : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run the above commands using the most recent version of GeMTC (0.8-4), which was released to CRAN a few days ago, and it works for me. There were a few fixes rolled into the release, so it's possible that upgrading will fix this issue for you. If not, please share the details of your environment (operating system, R version, package versions).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked fine after installing the GeMTC (0.8-4) version.